# How to deny path in k8S ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I would like to block `/public/configs` in my k8s ingress.

My current settings doesnt work.

```
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-myapp
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /public/configs
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-myapp
                port:
                  number: 88 // fake port
```

Is there any better (easy) way?

Answer (score 6):

1- Create a dummy service and send it to that:

```
  - path: /public/configs
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    backend:
      service:
        name: dummy-service
        port:
          number: 80
```

2- use `server-snippets` as bellow to return 403 or any error you want:

a) for k8s nginx ingress:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* "^/public/configs" {
          deny all;
          return 403;
        }
```

b) for nginx ingress:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.org/server-snippet: |
      location ~* "^/public/configs" {
          deny all;
          return 403;
        }
```